# How to retrieve a view column derivation in PostgreSQL or Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I want to retrieve the derivation expression of a column in a view, and I want to do it dynamically from within a stored procedure, so psql \d+ or pgAdmin is no use to me.

Where can I retrieve this information from? The full text is in pg_views but I'd rather not get into slicing this string up to try and find each of the column expressions.

Comment: can you give a specific example? not understanding what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as chosen if you're satisified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-views.html)

> Views in PostgreSQL are implemented using the rule system.

So essentially, they get rewritten to simply SELECT statemetns. Nothing in the catalog stores the column expression. Internally, when you run `\d` on a view, it calls [`pg_catalog.pg_get_viewdef`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html). You can't go further from that with the system catalog. You're going to have to [parse that query](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Query_Parsing) to get to the column expression, perhaps with something like `libpg_query`.